# Javascript Code wont run when changing TextBox Format

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

Hi i am using below java script code to make some calculation in asp grid-view

the code wont run if i change textbox format in the grid-view

for example

```
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtCalcCommision" TextMode="Number" placeholder="Eenter Commision" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"  ></asp:TextBox>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

other than the code runs perfectly

javascript code

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("[id*=GvProducts]input[type=text][id*=txtCalc]").on('keyup', (function (e) {

            var Costprice = $(this).closest('tr').find("input[type=text][id*=txtCalcCostPrice]").val();
            var quantity = $(e.target).closest('tr').find("input[type=text][id*=txtCalcQuantity]").val();
            var Commision = $(this).closest('tr').find("input[type=text][id*=txtCalcCommision]").val();
            var getunitprice = (parseFloat(Commision / 100 * Costprice)) + parseFloat(Costprice);
            var total = getunitprice * quantity;
            $(e.target).closest('tr').find("[id*=lblunitprice]").text(getunitprice);
            $(e.target).closest('tr').find("[id*=lblTotal]").text(total);
            GrossTotal();
        }));

    });

    var gross;

    function GrossTotal() {

        gross = 0;

        $("[id*=GvProducts][id*=lblTotal]").each(function (index, item) {
            gross = gross + parseInt($(item).text());
        });
        $("[id*=lblGrandTotal]").text(gross);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: what part doesn't work ? 'keyup' ?

Comment: @tnw: his markup is asp.net html

Comment: yes keyup doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Add `ClientIDMode="Static"` to the textbox. ASP.NET will change the ID when the page is rendered, unless you set ClientIDMode to "Static".

Also have you tried putting a `debugger;` line inside the keyup function? It might be hitting the line, but the code in the function isn't running properly.

`[id*=GvProducts]` this isn't included in your HTML that you provided. I can't really tell if that's affecting the CSS selector from finding your textbox control.

`<ItemTemplate>` assumes that this is coming from a repeater... in that case, you're better off using `$("input.form-control")` to find your control. ASP.NET will do a whole bunch of things to uniqueify the ID when it's inside a repeater.

Comment: what you mentioned about ClientIDMode="Static" is true. However, he is using jquery contains selector which would mean id like '%txtCalc%'

Comment: Yeah I noticed, but it's inside a repeater. I think the whole ID will be lost and converted something else. I'll check what happens in my app to an ID inside a repeater. You're definitely right about the GVProducts bit, since we can't see that in the HTML posted.

Comment: hi i tried to add ClientIDMode="Static" still have the issue

Comment: @Ayman were you able to test whether the keyup function is actually called by adding a debugger line?

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:**

Change :

```
 $("[id*=GvProducts]input[type=text][id*=txtCalc]").on('keyup', (function (e) {
```

to

```
 $("[id$=txtCalcCommision]").on('keyup', (function (e) {
```

Since the id is unique, a simple ends with selector would do the job.

**Option 2 :**

Since you are not using  `ClientIDMode="Static"` as mentioned by @Nick, you need to get the server generated id as a selector id.

`$("<%=txtCalcCommision.ClientID%>").on('keyup', (function (e) {`

**Option 3 :**

Add `ClientIDMode="Static"` to the asp.net control :

`<asp:TextBox ID="txtCalcCommision"`ClientIDMode="Static"`TextMode="Number" placeholder="Eenter Commision" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"  ></asp:TextBox>`

```
$("#txtCalcCommision").on('keyup', (function (e) {
```

Comment: hi tried both  Option 1 and 2 didn't work i have noticed in java script code input[type=text] maybe if change type to number will work

Comment: they are unique  the issue is when i remove TextMode="Number" the code works